# class importing in implementing error on ng serve

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cdk, nebular, serve

X [ERROR] TS2610: 'sticky' is defined as an accessor in class 'CdkColumnDef', but is overridden here in 'NbColumnDefDirective' as an instance property. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
node_modules/@nebular/theme/components/cdk/table/cell.d.ts:38:4:
  38 │     sticky: boolean;
     ╵     ~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] TS2610: 'sticky' is defined as an accessor in class 'CdkHeaderRowDef', but is overridden here in 'NbHeaderRowDefDirective' as an instance property. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
node_modules/@nebular/theme/components/cdk/table/row.d.ts:29:4:
  29 │     sticky: boolean;
     ╵     ~~~~~~
```

X [ERROR] TS2610: 'sticky' is defined as an accessor in class 'CdkFooterRowDef', but is overridden here in 'NbFooterRowDefDirective' as an instance property. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
node_modules/@nebular/theme/components/cdk/table/row.d.ts:39:4:
  39 │     sticky: boolean;
     ╵     ~~~~~~
```

when running serve on, it fails with above error

i tried upgrading typescript-plugin-rxjs from 4.0.4 to 5.0.3 but the error still persists. Tried upgrading angular/cdk and and angular/core to version 17.2.2, but still does not work. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please also add Code for Better understanding of the issue.

Comment: i am actually using an external lib A from which i am importing data. which eventually results in error.


the code is listed below

@Input() sticky: boolean;

  /** Whether this column should be sticky positioned on the end of the row */
  @Input()
  get stickyEnd(): boolean {
    return this._stickyEnd;
  }
  set stickyEnd(value: boolean) {
    const prevValue = this._stickyEnd;
    this._stickyEnd = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
    this._hasStickyChanged = prevValue !== this._stickyEnd;
  }

Comment: Maybe you can share HTML & TS code for table.that will help for better understanding.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue after updating angular16 to 17 - I also updated nebular/theme from 12 to 13

Comment: there is an issue raised on github: https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/3246 "skipLibCheck": true under compilerOtions on the tsconfig file worked for me as a temp workaround

Comment: i tries that solution that is mentioned in there native issues. it does not work for me. i figured out that this is something to do with the tsconfig file. typescript configuration had caused millions errors in the past